# What is the value of "Drupal user" in Drush status for?

Tags: users, drush, staging

What is the value of "Drupal user" in Drush status for? Suddenly, one of my websites lists the Drupal user as "anonymous" instead of blank, like the other environments. I noticed the change after pulling in code from the repo and the data from production, but it may have always been like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value "Drupal user" is the user the Drush command is run as. You can supply a (valid) user name to any Drush command using `-u` - for example `drush status -u admin`. Your implicit question, why did the status command suddenly report "anonymous" as the user, I can not answer. You would have examine the code you pulled - maybe something in the settings?

Comment: Thanks for the info! I suspect that it's always reported anonymous as the user, but I just didn't notice it before.